# How to integrate PayPal Payouts AAC?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have been trying to integrate PayPal Payouts (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/) but it does not seem to work even with a simple setup just to display the Login with Paypal button. I'm trying to setup this https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/features/set-up-assisted-account-creation to get the `payer_id`. I'll store the `payer_id` in the database then I'll process these ids with PayPal Payouts batch processing to pay the users.

This is the simplest setup -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>PayPal Payouts</title>
        <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/payouts/js/payouts_aac.js"></script>
        <script>
            paypal.PayoutsAAC.render({
            // Use sandbox for testing
            env: 'sandbox',
            clientId: {
                // production: '<production clientId>',
                sandbox: '**************************************************************'
            },
            merchantId: '*************',
            pageType: 'login',
            onLogin: function (response) {
                if (response.err) {
                console.log(response.err)
                } else {
                console.log(response.body.code)
                }
            }
            }, '#paypal')
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="paypal"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It just appearing momentarily. Only on first page loads it appears then it is disappearing.
After disappearance it is yielding an error on the console -

```
main.js:596 Uncaught TypeError: Parameter `locale` must be a string, not undefined `undefined`
    at o (main.js:596)
    at i (main.js:596)
    at new t (main.js:596)
    at Object.createHandler (main.js:614)
    at t.init (main.js:1389)
    at Object../bootstrap.js (main.js:1257)
    at i (main.js:1)
    at Object../render.js (main.js:1353)
    at i (main.js:1)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:1323)
```

I'm attaching a console.log screenshot -
[image]

This is the first time page loads screenshot -
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For AAC https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/features/set-up-assisted-account-creation , as that documentation indicates:

> Contact your PayPal account manager to enable identity services.

Have you done this? If not, you are attempting to integrate something you do not have access to.

The particular error message and problem you are having is not important, since you are attempting to use something you cannot use regardless.

Comment: Even for a testing environment, does it required?

Comment: i have created a business account to get the merchant id and I have used the sandbox client id. Isn't it all that required?

Comment: Please reply just for testing purpose, even for testing environment does this required (identity services) ?

Comment: It is required.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Hey, have you figured this out yet, having the same problem!